# submitting hidden fields and or mysql relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form submitted in rails where a user enters their zip code. I have a table with thousands and thousands of zip codes along with their respective longitude and latitude.

Is there a way I can setup some hidden form fields or in the controller, pull the long and lat from the zipcode table and save them into the user profile?

Or maybe set up a relationship in the database that does this?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options, putting the zip with the longitude and latitude inside the user model (being unnormalized), or having a one to many relationship between users and the zip (normalized)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zip
end

class Zip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :autosave => true
end
```

Then in your view you can have:

```
<% semantic_form_for @user do |form| %>
   standard form input stuff here.
   <%= text_field_tag "zip_text" %> # This puts a text field in the form that is not 
   #tied to the user. Thus when the form is submitted, if you examine the params hash you 
   #will see that the field zip_text is not within the user hash. Indeed it will be 
   #structured like this params = {:type => "commit", :id => 1, :zip_text => 96822, 
   #:users_attributes => {Users stuff in here}}
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller you can have:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@zip = Zip.find(params[:zip_text])
@user.zip << @zip
@user.save
```

To me it's more efficient to do it this way, and have the zip input be a plain text input, then have the zip lookup and subsequent relation (done with the <<) handled in the controller, especially if you're going to have several thousand zip codes.